# merging two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, merge

I'm having two sets of vectors as follows:

```
a1 = [0,1,2,3,4]; % the unique elements 
b1=[12,35,60,20,7]; % the number of repitition of each element
a2 = [0,1,6]; % the unique elements 
b2=[15,40,2]; % the number of repitition of each element
```

and I would like to merge them to get this result:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,6];
b=[27,75,60,20,7,2];
```

Is there any built-in function in Matlab that does it?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows:

1. The first ouput of [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) gives the desired `a`. The third output gives positive integer labels, `u`, that identify the groups.
2. To sum the elements of each group, call [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with `u` as first input.

Code:

```
[a, ~, u] = unique([a1(:); a2(:)]);
a = a(:).';
b = accumarray(u, [b1(:); b2(:)]).';
```